# Are the English surname "Douglas" and the Old Slavonic word глас (glas) "voice" cognates?

Tags: etymology

Are the English surname "Douglas" and the Old Slavonic word глас (glas) "voice" cognates?

, taking into consideration, that glais means “stream” and that "voice" is also a speech stream.

Answer (score 9):

(I’m not sure this is really about English as such, given that one is a Celtic word and the other a Slavic word – but *Douglas* is an English name, so let’s give it the benefit of the doubt.)

### tl;dr

These two words are not cognates, no.

- In the Slavic word, the reference to the voice as a stream of words is secondary: the primary meaning is the sound itself.
- In the Celtic word, the reference to streams of water is also secondary: the primary meaning is the blue-greenish colour of bodies of water.

In other words, they belong to two completely separate groups of words whose meanings happen to have been extended in such a way that they overlap somewhat.

### Slavic *глас*

The [Wiktionary article on Proto-Slavic **golsъ*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/gols%D1%8A) (the direct ancestor of the Old Church Slavonic word) derives the word from the Proto-Indo-European root **gels-* meaning ‘call’, but this is not a commonly accepted root – I’m not sure where it was taken from here. A root **gelH-* (or perhaps **gleH-*) has been suggested by at least Peter Schrijver, but it is not included in [LIV²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexikon_der_indogermanischen_Verben).

What is certain, however, is that there is a cluster of words relating to voice, calling, noise, etc., which have a structure that points back to a PIE consonant skeleton of **gl(H)(s)*; the Wiktionary article on [*call*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/call#Etymology) gives a good selection of cognates.

Importantly, none of these words refer to streams or anything like that – they all refer to vocal sounds. Some, like Latin *gallus* ‘rooster’, would be quite far-fetched if the original meaning of the root had been ‘stream [of words]’.

### Goidelic *glas*

As you mention, *Douglas* comes from Scottish *dubhghlas* ‘blackstream’, which also exists in Irish and Manx, the other two languages in the Goidelic branch of the Celtic languages. In this word, the second part, *glas*, does indeed mean a stream, but that does not appear to be the original meaning – the original (and to this day more common) meaning of the word is ‘blue-green’ (can refer to either blue or green, depending on context). Cognates from continental Celtic languages like Gaulish show that this word comes from Proto-Celtic **glasto-* with the same meaning: in Goidelic, **st* became *ss* (reduced to *s* when word-initial or word-final), but the attested Gaulish form is *glastum* with the *t* intact, a derived noun that refers to [woad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isatis_tinctoria).

Ranko Matasović’s [*Etymological Dictionary of Proto-Celtic*](https://books.google.dk/books?id=YN_YPQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) takes PC **glasto-* as being from PIE **ĝʰlh<sub>3</sub>-stó-*, a derivation from the PIE root [**ĝʰelh<sub>3</sub>-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/%C7%B5%CA%B0elh%E2%82%83-) ‘gleam, glow; green, yellow’. This root underlies a whole slew of words related to green-, yellow- or shininess, from Greek [*χλωρός*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%87%CE%BB%CF%89%CF%81%CF%8C%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) (whence *chlorine*, from its colour) to English [*yellow*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yellow#Etymology).

The meaning of the root changed a bit in Celtic: where in PIE, it referred to the part of the colour spectrum ranging from yellowish to greenish, in Celtic it had shifted to the part ranging from greenish to bluish. This includes the colour of various bodies of water which then metonymically became ‘the blue-green ones’ (cf. how phrases like ‘out of the blue’ refer to air as being blue, even though it’s not). Even in Modern Irish (perhaps Scottish too, I’m not sure), the ocean can still be called *glasmhuir* (‘blue-green sea’).

So *Dubhghlas* means ‘dark stream’, yes, but really it means ‘the dark blue-green one’.

Comment: Not far fetched at all, comparing *Kehle* "throat", [Luft-]Röhre* "larynx", *Rohr, Röhre* "tube", *röhren* "roar, shout". Diminutiv *-Kehlchen* appears as part of bird names and can be compared to *nighting-gale*. Words like *Schlund* "mouth" on the other hand are figurativel for parts of water ways (or originally, if YMMV). Stream would be an abstraction, maybe, sure, but perhaps a rather potent one.

Comment: @vectory Well, it’s quite common, cross-linguistically, for rivers to have mouths; it’s a very obvious metaphor which is, unsurprisingly, commonly employed. German _Rohr/Röhre_ and _röhren_ aren’t related, though – that’s just another case of two somewhat similar words developing meanings that partly overlap. Their similarity has probably helped the overlap, but they are ultimately separate words with separate meanings (‘reed’ and ‘bellow’).

Comment: Oh that may just show how old and entangled these roots are. Reed has IMHO a certain sygnificance to writing, so not all that old, but pretty old, and potentially spread from one source.

Comment: @vectory They’re not really entangled, though, except in Modern German. Both are only attested in Germanic languages, but their oldest attestations and comparative evidence point to PG forms like _*rairija-_ for the shouty verb and _*rauza-_ for the plant noun. There’s no reason to believe those two words are in any way related; all they have in common is an initial r followed by a diphthong.

Comment: Sounds like you looked it up. I have no idea which plant noun? Is it *Strohalm* "straw"? The roots are suffixed according to PoS, the vocalism can be ignored; R (the second one in rair-) would be deleted before z, I guess, at least it, "-aurz-", *would feel intuitively complicated to me*, and the noun root surely reminds of *raunzen*, *ranzen*, *raunen* "roar, rant, scold"; I wonder what comparanda your sources chose. *Röhre* indeed can be translated as a loud, sonorant voice.

Comment: @vectory The ‘plant nount’ is _*rauza-_ ‘reed’ (as opposed to the ‘shouty verb’ _*rairija-_). The vocalism cannot “be ignored” – that’s not how Indo-European languages work. PG _*-ai-_ and _*-au_ do not correspond in any way, and there is no way I know of to reconcile _*rairija-_ and _*rauza-_ as being from the same root. _*rairz-_ or _*raurz-_ would be phonotactically impossible in Germanic and wouldn’t explain anything anyway. Also, I cannot find any indication in Duden, LEO, Wiktionary, etc. that _Röhre_ can mean ‘loud, sonorant voice’; please cite your source for that claim.

Comment: Oh, over night I had forgotten that part of your earlier comment. Thanks for clarifying. I know *Schilfrohr*, but I had thought that secondary. What's your source? My source for "Röhre" is my grandma speaking about Tina Turner... it can be found repeatedly said about that singer, e.g. "Hits der Rock- und Popröhre" (figuratively), or describing a voice or its quality. Also, *Organ* sometimes means *[powerful] voice-organ*, which in turn may relate in a play of words ambiguously to the instrument, *pipe organ*. *roar*, PIE \*rey- may well be compared to \*Hreg-, etc. (cf. *rechnen, rex, rect-*).

Comment: cp. Ger. *Rachen* "throat, glottis", *rufen* (roep, call, shout, message, request), *Verruf* "dysphemistic", *verrucht* (infamous), *guter Ruf* "good standing, good name", *Rufname* "call name" (opposed to formal name), *raufen* "collect, bunch, reap, rear", *Haufen* "heap", *rupfen, ruppen* "to plug, pick, rip" ... *rar* "rare", *Ruhr* (a river/region, uncertain, possibly *rift valley*), *rühren, regen* "to stir, move, excite", *Regen* "rain", *Roggen, Reisig, Rattan" (plants and products), *rund* "round", *rinnen* "to flow", *Rinne* "gutter" ... *[Ofen]Rohr* even made it into Serbo-Croation.